# Dynamically Generate Web-Pages for ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, video

Currently I'm doing a project where in the user uploads a Video from the website. I am looking to dynamically create a Web-Page for the Video the user has uploaded. This is something that Youtube does. When we upload a video in Youtube, it automatically creates a URL that hosts the uploaded video.

How can we do that in ASP.NET?

Comment: it's not like you create a page for every work you just keep some id against that and a single page on the basis of id displays that.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube doesn't create any page, it already have that page (the same for every video), and it is filled with properties of the specified video when loaded. 
You should assign a new id to the uploaded video and reference it in your page: myvideopage.com?videoId=XXX been XXX the generated id.